# How to find the index of the center element of a 2d array using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say we have an image which a 2d array like this:

```
var img = [
    [
      { r: 255, g: 255, b: 255 },
      { r: 255, g: 255, b: 255 },
      { r: 255, g: 255, b: 255 }
    ],
    [
      { r: 255, g: 255, b: 255 },
      { r: 255, g: 255, b: 255 },
      { r: 255, g: 255, b: 255 }
    ],
    [
      { r: 255, g: 255, b: 255 },
      { r: 255, g: 255, b: 255 },
      { r: 255, g: 255, b: 255 }
    ]
  ];
```

We have a 3x3 matrix. Each record represents a pixel.
Now the middle element is the fifth record or Img[1][1].

I want to be able to find the index of the middle element in any odd number square matrix. How can I do this?

I have tried thinking about this and thought about using the modulus operator.
We would have let's a 5x5 matrix which means 25 pixels. I would then try to divide 25 by 2:

25/2 =  12 with a remainder 25 mod 2 = 1.
Therefore the middle element would be 12 + 1 = 13.

Because we have a 5x5 matrix this means that each line in the matrix contains 5 elements.
We would have to do:

1. 13/5 = 2 meaning we have to go through 2 lines of 5. Which mean we can skip directly from img[0][x] , img[1][x]  to [2][x]. (Skipping to the third line)
2. 13 mod 5 = 3 to get the index inside the line we're in meaning img[2][3] but this is wrong because 13 would be in the third spot but with index 2 because 0,1,2 so we would have img[2][2].

Doing for 7x7 matrix I notice a pattern for 3x3 we had img[1][1], for 5x5 we had img[2][2], for 7x7 we have img[3][3].

So my trouble with all of this is I do not now for sure if it applies for all even numbers and how to translate it to a javascript code.

Comment: Is it always symmetrical? Or can you have a 5x3 matrix? Or can you even have different number of elements `[[1, 2], [1], [1, 2, 3]]`?

Comment: On a separate note, you seem to be overthinking it for symmetrical odd-numbered matrices. With a 5x5 matrix, you don't need to calculate the total fields, just take the middle of the first array `5 / 2 = 2` (rounded down/integer division), then take the middle of that array which is `5 / 2` again. So `m[2][2]`. Works for any odd-numbered matrix that has the same number of columns and rows.

Comment: oh thanks. Yeah I tend to overthink sometimes.

Comment: @Nassims, note that in your example with the 5x5 matrix **you forgot to subtract 1**. The "middle element" is indeed the 13th *element* as you said, but as the indices *begin at 0* you should subtract 1 to get its *index*... 13-1=12, and 12-10=2, as you'd expect... :)

Answer (score 1):

```
const row    = img[Math.floor(img.length / 2)];
const result = row[Math.floor(row.length / 2)];
```

No need for modulo here